# Hide Dropdown based on URL change

Tags: reactjs

I want to hide a dropdown based on URL Change. In some URL, i dont want to show dropdown.

```
<Row>
            <Col lg="12" style={{ paddingTop: "15px" }}>
              <select id="facility_id" className="form-control select2" value={this.state.selected_facility_id} onChange={this.handleChange} title="Type of system">
                <Route exact path='/production-list' component={ProductionList} />
                {this.state.facilities.map((faci, key) =>
                  <option key={key} value={faci.facility_id}>{faci.facility_name}</option>
                  // <DropdownItem>{faci.facility_name}</DropdownItem>

                )}
              </select>
        
            </Col>
          </Row>
```

I am new to react . So can anyone help?

Comment: What's the URL structure??are you using react-router??

Comment: yes. I am using react- router-dom

Comment: Can you post example of your routes..Where you would want to show and hide the component